# Select one entity from doctrine query response array

Tags: php, orm, doctrine, symfony

I am running the following query to fetch two entities from the database.

```
   return $this->createQueryBuilder('a')
        ->select('a','u')
        ->where('a.api_key = :api_key')
        ->leftJoin(User::class, 'u', \Doctrine\ORM\Query\Expr\Join::WITH, 'a.user_id = u.id')
        ->setParameter('api_key', $key)
        ->getQuery()
        ->getResult();
```

The query returns two entities as expected. However, the response is in the format of an indexed array.

```
array(2) {
    [0]=> object(AppBundle\Entity\ApiKey)
    [1]=> object(AppBundle\Entity\User)
}
```

Do you know if there is a way in doctrine to get the response to be returned as an associative array, using the entity name as the index? Or is there a doctrine function that can select one entity from the query response?

I only ask because I don't really like doing this:

```
 $apiKey = null;
 $username = null;
 foreach ($result as $row) {
     if($row instanceof ApiKey::class){
         $apiKey = $row->getApikKey(); 
     }
     if($row instanceof User::class){
         $user = $row->getUsername();
     }
 }
```

And would prefer being able do to something like this:

```
 $apiKey = $result [ApiKey::class]->getApiKey();
 $username = $result [User::class]->getUsername();
```

Comment: You  can make custom doctrine hydrator.

Comment: Please could you provided an example, i'm not very familiar with doctrine hydrator's.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code:

```
$entities = $this->createQueryBuilder('a')
        ->select('a','u')
        ->where('a.api_key = :api_key')
        ->leftJoin(User::class, 'u', \Doctrine\ORM\Query\Expr\Join::WITH, 'a.user_id = u.id')
        ->setParameter('api_key', $key)
        ->getQuery()
        ->getResult();

$returnArray = array();
foreach ($entities as $entity) {
    $returnArray[get_class($entity)] = $entity;
}

return $returnArray;
```

If you want to have it much better done, try this code:

```
<?php
namespace My\Doctrine\Hydration;
use Doctrine\ORM\Internal\Hydration\ObjectHydrator;

class ClassArrayObjectHydrator extends ObjectHydrator
{
    protected function hydrateAllData()
    {
        $result = parent::hydrateAllData();

        return $this->toClassArray($result);
    }

    protected function toClassArray(array $result)
    {
        $returnArray = array();

        foreach ($result as $entity) {
            $returnArray[get_class($entity)] = $entity;
        }

        return $returnArray;
    }    
}
```

app/config/config.yml

```
orm:
     entity_managers:
       default:
         mappings: ~
         hydrators:
             ClassArrayObject: \My\Doctrine\Hydration\ClassArrayObjectHydrator
```

your query:

```
return $this->createQueryBuilder('a')
            // ...
            ->getResult('ClassArrayObject');
```

Comment: So i did think about doing ^ this. But it doesn't seem right to have to do this every time I write a query which calls a join. Hence why I was wondering if doctrine had some kind of built in method for formatting the response.

Comment: I've created the new hydrator as per your changes ^ however I run into this exception: Warning: get_class() expects parameter 1 to be object, array given

Comment: Paste var_dump of `$result` in `hydrateAllData`

Comment: array(2) {
  [0]=>
  &array(3) {
    ["user_id"]=>
    int(1)
    ["api_key"]=>
    string(4) "2222"
    ["expires"]=>
    object(DateTime)#407 (3) {
      ["date"]=>
      string(26) "2017-03-06 00:00:00.000000"
      ["timezone_type"]=>
      int(3)
      ["timezone"]=>
      string(13) "Europe/Berlin"
    }
  }
  [1]=>
  &array(5) {
    ["id"]=>
    int(1)
    ["username"]=>
    string(5) "admin"
    ["email"]=>
    string(14) "admin@live.net"
    ["salt"]=>
    string(3) "111"
    ["password"]=>
    string(3) "111"
  }
}

Comment: Sorry, you should extend ObjectHydrator instead of ArrayHydrator. An edit made.